# What can cause "Lost connection to MySQL server during query"?

Tags: docker, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an application which uses `flask-sqlalchemy` with a MySQL database.

My code is similar to the following:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()

my_object = models.Foobar(foo=foo, bar=bar)
db.session.add(my_object)
db.session.commit()

# identifier = Do something that requires the object to be in the db. Needs ~1s.
# The code here uses from multiprocessing import Process and the db

# Update my_object
my_object.foo = identifier
db.session.commit()
```

When I execute the code directly, it works. When I execute it in a Docker container, I get:

```
OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

The [full traceback](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e46901ca9501078846ac75c7dd6a94a) seems not to provide more useful information.

A common reason for this bug seems `SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE`, but I guess the default of `flask-sqlachemy` (2 hours) is fine?

So what could be the problem and how can I fix it?

(I guess it is related to the new process which also uses the database)

### What I use

```
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.2
Flask==0.12.2
SQLAlchemy==1.1.13
```

Comment: You are not using `create_engine` or anything as such to init the DB? need to see the initialization part

Comment: Also see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405808/sqlalchemy-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: I use flask-sqlalchemy: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/

Comment: It's happening for every single request?

Comment: Only in this multiprocessing scenario and only with docker (or at least more often with docker). By docker I mean docker compose, one container for the DB and one for the app

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting 10 seconds or more after running docker. I got a similar problem in my unittest using docker with mysql, it may takes several seconds to complete initialization, so I sleep 10 seconds before using sqlalchemy to connect mysql.